# About version of Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If the request does not specify a version, e.g. `/me/friends`, which version of Graph API is used? Does it automatically use the latest version, such as v2.2? Or it uses the oldest version v1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Read the topic: "What happens if I don't specify a version for an API?"
It says it would use the oldest version as default

Right now it would be using 1.0

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions